# Docker stuck at npm install

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I have a project that I want to dockerize. I run `npm install` and `npm build` with no problem on my computer, but it has some problems when I build with Docker.

Docker output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  56.96MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:12.2.0-alpine
---> f391dabf9dce
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> b50a8efbf074
Step 3/7 : ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
---> Using cache
---> 3358967a13ab
Step 4/7 : COPY package.json /app/package.json
---> Using cache
---> 851ac31a0adb
Step 5/7 : RUN npm install
---> Running in 8cc36a435cec
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
```

It is stuck in this here:

Dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I have done this with other dockerfiles, but the result was the same.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "express": "^4.17.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Remove the `--silent` and check the logs.

Comment: @rdas it does not go to that place cause it stucks at stage 5 and that is npm install

Comment: I run your code and everything works. What Docker version are you using?

Comment: what OS are you using ?

Comment: Offtopic but you already have react-srcripts in your package so you are trying to install 2.1.8 and then 3.0.1 in your docker. you can totally avoid it by just bumping version in your package.

Comment: @rafaelncarvalho my docker version is 18.09.2, build 6247962

Comment: @VnoitKumar ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Rikin you are right but the problem is that it stops at npm install and doesnt go further

Comment: are you behind proxy?

Answer (score 0):

So, this might be a temporary solution till this is properly addressed, but you can use

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I have used it for docker environment and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

when ever you run `docker run my-image` it will run in a new container and previous container remain unused,
we can use `docker build location-of-the-Dockerfile --no-cache` switch to not using cached images but it didn't work for me
in my case, removing unused containers and images fixed the problem ,

remove all containers > `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)` 
remove all images if you want >> `docker image rm $(docker images -q)`

Answer (score 0):

I had to the same problem resently.

I had to add the following `npm ci --force` instead.

Then it took quite some time to load but worked at the end.

[why `npm ci` and not `npm i`?](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci)

> - The project must have an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json.
> - If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in package.json, npm ci will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.
> - npm ci can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.
> - If a node_modules is already present, it will be automatically removed before npm ci begins its install.
> - It will never write to package.json or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes for restriction issues we have to use proxy in npm config.
but mostly using yarn instead npm solve the problem.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same issue. I just waited for 1 hour and it went to the next step.

Edit :
While building the npm install downloads all the packages and it takes time to do that, it depends on the size of your application how long will it take.